# Security issues with applet

Tags: java, applet

I  have developed an applet. But when my browser fetches it from the webserver it pops a security warring. I don't want this message to come. Meaning applet should run without the end users permession. How can I do that? Do I need to get my applet signed? If yes, from where can i get it signed? What's the cost of geting it signed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description might relate to a number of problems, such as the code trying to do things which require trust.  That does not sound like the case in this instance.  If your unsigned code tried to do things that required trust, it would not prompt the user at start-up, but either prompt them when the trusted action is attempted (e.g. for cross site access in later JREs) or just fail with an AccessControlException or similar.

It could be that your applet uses multiple Jars and has run into the [mixed code restrictions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html) introduced in Java 1.6.0_20.  But the symptoms do not sound quite right for that either.

Is your applet publicly available?  What is the URL where I/we can visit it?

As an aside, if your applet tries to break out of the security sand-box, it must be trusted.  That means the code must be digitally signed, and OK'd by the end user at the prompt.  There is no way around it.

But it does not require a code signing certificate issued from a CA.  You can roll your own code signing certificate using the tools of the SDK.  I have a few small demos. of code projects that compile and build code before signing it.

Comment: For the demos., try the filetest.zip available at the demo. of the JNLP API FileContents object(1).  The build.xml should build and run just fine in any modern IDE (E.G. Eclipse, Netbeans..)  Look at the build.xml for how to do it.  1) http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs

Answer (score 0):

You need to get yourself a code-signing certificate. Probably by some "well-known" CA if you want to avoid all warnings. The certificate itself costs money, but once you have it, you can use it to sign as many applets as you want (you do the signing yourself).